# Dynamically changing table rows based on screen size Vuejs

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, html-table, screen-size

I have a table with two `<tr>` tags as its first row (I know but unfortunately it has to be this way):

tag one:

```
<tr class="abc"
    @click="expanFunc">
```

tag two:

```
<tr class="abc">
```

I want my table to show only tag one if the screen size is either large or medium and tag two if my screen size is small or xs. I need this to happen dynamically without refreshing the page. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the @media in css? You could give the tr you want to hide a class and then make it hidden based off screen size with visibility: hidden;

```
<tr class="abc ExampleClass">

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .ExampleClass{
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```

This will hide anything using that class when the screen size is 600px or less.

Comment: That works but this way it only hides it based on screen size. Is there a way not to render it at all based on screen size?

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look into this: [vue-mq](https://github.com/AlexandreBonaventure/vue-mq)

Here's another [reference](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/vuejs-vue-media-queries) by DigitalOcean.

You can assign breakpoints based on your screen sizes. In your case, that would be XS, small, medium, and large.

I haven't tested this out, but maybe you can do something like this (after installing the plugin):

```
<tr class="abc" @click="expanFunc" :mq="['medium', 'large']">
<tr class="abc" :mq="['xs', 'small']">
```